# How to trace .net code deployed in remote server

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

I have deployed my application to the remote server. But some error occures during that runs on the server. So i need to trace the server side code. I don't have Vs .net in my server but i have that in my client machine. Is there any way to trace the code from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the remote debugging feature of Visual Studio. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) for details on MSDN - and note, this is only available in the higher-priced editions.

Note that this uses a low-level remoting connection between the server and your client PC. Setting this up to work across firewalls can be very difficult. It also requires the Remote Debugging Monitor to be installed on the server-side, so it won't work on a server e.g. at an ISP over which you have no control.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the remote debugger. [See example here](http://www.tyronedavisjr.com/index.php/2008/04/14/my-experience-with-visual-studio-2008-remote-debugging/)